# ng-repeat in repeat does not repeat nested object angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a object with categories, inside this object there is a object called items which contain objects with items.

now i want to do in a repeat to display the items like this:

```
    <div ng-if="delivery_items" ng-repeat="(k, cat_item) in delivery_items">
        <div class="item-cat-header">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> {{cat_item.item_category_name}}
        </div>
        <div class="item-rule" ng-repeat="item in cat_item.items">
            <div class="item-info">
                {{item.item_name}}
                <p class="item-desc"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-price">
                €
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but for some reason it shows a error

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: item in cat_item.items, Duplicate key: undefined:undefined, Duplicate value: undefined
```

the json object looks like this:[image: json object]

what am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

the array creation part:

```
            //set menu list
        if ($scope.categories_norm) {
            $scope.delivery_items = {};

            //get categories
            angular.forEach(data.item_categories.normal_categories, function (v, k) {
                //push categories
                $scope.delivery_items[v.item_category_id] = v; //create empty catagory object
                $scope.delivery_items[v.item_category_id]['items'] = [];


                if ($scope.items) {

                    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (val, key) {
                        if (v.item_category_id == val.item_category_id) {
                            $scope.delivery_items[v.item_category_id]['items'][key] = val;
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: You have holes in the array. It is not properly indexed.. you can quick fix by doing a track by $index in the second ng-repeat but you should fix your array.

Comment: yes this shows the right data but it also shows a lot of empty rows now? I also dont understand the holes part?

Comment: Added explanation..hope that clarifies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because of holes in the array (sparse array). I can see your first `item` array is of length 39 but you really do not have 39 items in the array. It is quite visible by looking at your snapshot (0, 9, 16,22 etc..). `ng-repeat` attaches a tracking id by default (unless you set a `track by`) to each repeated item as a `$hashkey` property, but when one of the items is not available it is literally `undefined` (`items[1]`) so that (`undefined`) will be set as key, but then again it gets another undefined item (`items[2]`) so it throws duplicate in repeater error. You can quick fix by doing a `track by $index`.

```
 <div class="item-rule" ng-repeat="item in cat_item.items track by $index">
```

But now it will show empty `item-rule` sections. So you should look to fix the array itself by cleaning up or setting the values properly. Check your array creation part.

---

*Update after array creation part was added into the question*

Your problem lies in the second loop (see comment before `if`).

```
angular.forEach($scope.items, function (val, key) {
   //If the condition here is not met you basically skip that index in the array
   //Remember key represents index of the original array you are iterating through
   if (v.item_category_id == val.item_category_id) {
         $scope.delivery_items[v.item_category_id]['items'][key] = val;
    }
});
```

change

```
$scope.delivery_items[v.item_category_id]['items'][key] = val;
```

to use `array.push`

```
$scope.delivery_items[v.item_category_id]['items'].push(val);
```

Comment: I understand your explaination, i have added the array create part. this happens because of the way it is. how can i improve that ?

Comment: ..just added a counter now and setted the counter, this works but now the first row is empty of every nested repeat

Comment: `$scope.delivery_items[v.item_category_id]['items'][key]` is your problem. instead of that use push.

Comment: Yes, the push worked!.. i had done this $scope.delivery_items[v.item_category_id]['items'][i] = val  and then a counter in the if else statement.. this also showed all items but then the first row was a empty row. dont know why

Comment: @rZaaaa that could be because you did not start with zero or increment it properly.

Comment: hmm.. i did start with zero.. but its not relevant anymore because your method works perfect, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="item-rule" ng-repeat="(key, item) in cat_item.items track by key" ng-if="item">
```

That is, if for some reason you have to work your way around a sparsed array in angular instead of reindexing it in the first place.